# How to use pandas to get data in between certain times within a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Here is a small snippet of a dataFrame I am working with:

```
     fruit       time
0    apple       2021-12-20 17:55:00
1    bannana     2021-12-23 05:13:00
2    apple       2021-12-20 17:55:00
```

How can I go about getting data in between certain timestamps. Such as all data in between 17:00:00 and 18:00:00.

In addition if possible, I would like to get data in between certain timestamps who's fruit value equals "apple"

I have tried df.between_time but I get the error: TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex.
Seems like the issue is with the timestamp formatting.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** boolean indexing to filter the rows where `hour` is between `17` and `18`:

```
df[df['fruit'].eq('apple') & df['time'].dt.hour.between(17, 18)]
```

**Solution 2:** Set the index to `time` column then use `between_time` to filter the rows

```
(
    df
    .set_index('time')
    .query("fruit == 'apple'")
    .between_time('17:00:00', '18:00:00')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Result

```
   fruit                time
0  apple 2021-12-20 17:55:00
2  apple 2021-12-20 17:55:00
```